# Будущее время для описания прошлых событий - что это за приём в лингвистике?

Tags: глаголы, лингвистика, будущее-время

Рассмотрим небольшой текст, в котором идёт самое обычное перечисление исторических событий:

> Весной 1820 года Александр Пушкин **отправился** в Кишинев, в канцелярию
> главного попечителя колонистов Южного края.
>
> В 1823 году Пушкин **переехал** в Одессу. Здесь он **устроился** в канцелярию
> графа Воронцова. Однако вскоре служебные и личные конфликты **привели** к
> тому, что Пушкин **попросил** отставки.

Я часто встречаюсь с альтернативной формой повествования подобных событий, которые УЖЕ произошли:

> Весной 1820 года Александр Пушкин **переедет** в Кишинев, в канцелярию
> главного попечителя колонистов Южного края.
>
> А в 1823 году Пушкин **переедет** в Одессу. Здесь он **устроится** в канцелярию
> графа Воронцова. Однако вскоре служебные и личные конфликты **приведут** к
> тому, что Пушкин **будет просить** отставку.

Есть ли в лингвистике какое-то определенное название для подобного рода повествования, с такими формами глаголов? То есть, когда речь идёт об УЖЕ произошедших событиях (как в примере выше, 1800-е года), но о них рассказывается как-будто в будущем времени («Пушкин **будет просить** отставку», «Личные конфликты **приведут** к тому, что ...»).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Рассмотрим небольшой текст, в котором идёт самое обычное перечисление исторических событий

Оно так и называется: "будущее историческое".

В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5#%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5). На [Русграме](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F#723). На Русграме стоит посмотреть весь раздел про нарративное употребление будущего времени.

Answer (score 5):

It's called the "[future in the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_in_the_past)" (*будущее в прошедшем*).

It's one of verb aspects, used with nested narrative frames: the main story set in the past, and the embedded narrative set in the future in regard to the main story.

In Russian, it's not marked grammatically, but in other languages (Bulgarian, English, Italian etc.) it is.

In 1820, in the past now but in the future relative to the story: "Pushkin **would** move to Kishinev" (not **will*); *Puškin si **sarebbe** trasferito a Kišinev* in Italian (not **sarà*), etc.

Comment: Very nice definition: `In 1820, in the past now but in the future relative to the story: `
Thanks!

Comment: That really is such a great way to put it. I always have trouble explaining that tense to Russian friends.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149496/discussion-on-answer-by-quassnoi-------)